# Countif until the last row in specific column is populated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with finishing my macro. It uses the COUNTIF function and checks the whole A column (A:A - no exclusions) against the data from B2. I would like to make the autofill in the C column until the last value in the B column - just like presented on the picture below:

[image]

Could anyone help me what should I add to my code to make this autofill possible??

```
Sub Countif()

Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-2],RC[-1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C2:C10").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You can also accomplish this by entering the formula in C2 and then double-clicking the fill-handle (lower right corner of the cell).

Comment: In cell C1 type `=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)` and then double click the fill handle (as per SomeSillyName's advice). That's the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna achieve using VBA try below code. Just Run the macro and it wud fill up the column C uptil values in column B.

```
Sub sample()

Dim LastRowColumnB As Long
LastRowColumnB = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowColumnB
    Cells(i, 3) = Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(i, 2))
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @ALL - thank you all for your posts below. All codes work but the code posted by user2063626 seems to be the fastest way and also the easiest way (as it also replaces countif formula to values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last row of a column like so:

```
Dim LastRowColumnB as Long
LastRowColumnB = Activesheet.Cells(Activesheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

and then modify your autofill to use that value.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & LastRowColumnB), Type:=xlFillDefault
```